# What's the difference between using 'mean(Complete_measurements$`High Freq (Hz)`)' and 'mean(Complete_measurements[4])'?

Tags: r, variables, mean

So I'm working through a multivariate analysis for a project and trying to familiarize myself with R as I do so, and I keep getting the error

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(Complete_measurements[4]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I'm not using 'mean.default' anywhere, but I have tracked the specific location to just my mean(complete_measurements[4])

I've noticed that when I instead use mean(Complete_measurements$`High Freq (Hz)`) it seems to work fine, but since I'm intending to use an array of data (ie columns 4-11), I was wondering if there was an easy solution to do so?

Thanks in advance!

So I've tried and gotten:

```
> mean(Complete_measurements$`High Freq (Hz)`)
[1] 6689.791
> mean(Complete_measurements[4])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(Complete_measurements[4]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I expected to get the same result for both? So the 6689.791, but I'm not sure why I get the error instead

Edit: while I get an answer when using '''mean(Complete_measurements[[4]])''', it gives me a different one - any reason why?

Comment: What is class `Complete_measurements` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `High Freq (Hz)` is 4th column? Check `names(Complete_measurements)[4]`